# How can I restrict access to a specific play route

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm working on an administrator area as a subproject of my main project. 
In my build file I have

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).dependsOn(admin)
```

and in my routes I have

```
->          /admin                                  admin.Routes
```

The admin area works fine, but I want to be able to restrict access to those users which have the role Admin.

I tried this Global

```
 @Override
    public Handler onRouteRequest(Http.RequestHeader request) {       
        if(UserInfo.getCurrent().hasRole(SecurityRole.Type.ADMIN)){
            if(request.path().startsWith("/admin")){
                return admin.Routes.routes().apply(Http.Context.current()._requestHeader());
            }
        }
        return super.onRouteRequest(request);    
    }
}
```

which grabs the user from the current context. But I get the error

```
RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
```

I suppose I could set up security in the admin area using Deadbolt, but I figured since the main file routes to the subproject there would be some easy way to just restrict access from the main project, but I haven't found anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would do it with Action Composition: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/JavaActionsComposition

Answer (score 2):

In my project, I use deadbolt, a module for play : https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java

It works very well.

You can restrict access to your controller with

```
@Restrict(@Group("admin"))
```

where admin is the role of your current user logged in. Check the docs!